# Summoning a specific entity in Minecraft using commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

What would be the command to summon a baby zombie that is *invisible* (not invincible), with oak leaves on its head, holding a stick, that follows you around?

If you could create the command for me, I would greatly appreciate it! :D

Comment: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10606/are-questions-regarding-minecrafts-commands-and-syntax-eligible-for-flagging I suggest you take a look here regarding why this question isn't up to standard. Long story short, you're asking us to create a command for you as opposed to helping you solve a problem with commands.

Comment: I would flag this question, but I don't know which flagging option to pick for questions that have zero research effort put into them.

Answer (score 1):

The command that will summon what you want is:

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~1 ~ {IsBaby:1,Equipment:[{id:"minecraft:stick"},{},{},{},{id:"minecraft:leaves"}],ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Amplifier:0,Duration:2147483647,ShowParticles:0b}]}
```

`IsBaby` makes the zombie a baby. The `Equipment` list specifies what it has in its hand (a stick) and head (leaves). In the `ActiveEffects` list is a potion effect with an `Id` of 14, which is invisibility.